# escaping sed characters java not working

Tags: java, string, unix, sed, escaping

I'll start with saying that I found a lot of topics simular to mine, but none were able to provide me with the correct answer.

I'm trying to insert a string into an xml file using following shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Config || exit 
sudo sed -i '/<\/home>/i <entry>'"$@"'</entry>' data.xml
```

when executing the script like this ./script.sh "test entry", my xml-file will look like this :

```
<home>
    <entry>test entry</entry>
</home>
```

which is what I want. But when I try to call this script trough java, I'm not able to successfully escape the quotes.

My java code is this :

```
String entry = "test entry";
String command = "/home/user/addentry.sh " + "\"" + entry + "\"";
Process p = null;
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {            
        p = run.exec(command);
    }     
    .....
```

When the code is executed my xml file looks like this :

```
<home>
    <entry>"test
</home>
```

As you can see, the quote is also passed as part of my input.
When changing the java code to :

```
String command = "/home/user/addentry.sh " + entry;
```

it works fine for strings without a space (so only 1 parameter for the script)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
package org.script.test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid arguments");
            return;
        }
        String entry="\"" +args[0]+ "\"";
        System.out.println("adding: " + entry);

        Process pr = null;
        try {
            pr =
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/oracle/testscript ; . ./test.sh " + entry });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Called by:

assume package `org.script.test`

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx128M -classpath testScript.jar org.script.test.Main "test entry"
```

It works even if you don't pass the arguments:

```
package org.mihai.script;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String entry = "test entry 2";
        System.out.println("adding: " + entry);

        Process pr = null;
        try {
            pr =
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/oracle/testscript ; . ./test.sh " + "\"" + entry +"\"" });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Call:

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx128M -classpath testScript.jar org.mihai.script.Main
```

Output data.xml:

```
<home>
<entry>test entry</entry>
<entry>test entry 2</entry>
</home>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ! But I'm afraid after executing the new code (I've tried both solutions) my new xml looks like this :

<home>
<entry></entry>
</home>

So I guess the parameter is not being passed ...

Comment: can you try changing your script to not use sudo? this is the script i used to test and it worked fine: #!/bin/bash
sed -i '/<\/home>/i <entry>'"$@"'</entry>' data.xml

Comment: and i hate to ask but did you change the strings to match your path and script name? i left the ones used on my machine in the example.

Comment: I found the issue, I replaced: "cd /home/oracle/testscript ; . ./test.sh " + "\"" + entry +"\""

into "/home/oracle/testscript/test.sh " + "\"" + entry +"\""

Thanks very much for your reply/answer !!!